# xpath - how extract html from one tag?

Tags: html, xpath, beautifulsoup, lxml

I need to extract html tags with text from one tag on page. For example:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <div class="post">
   text <p> text </p> text <a> text </a>
   <span> text </span>
  <div class="post">
   another text <p> text </p>
 </body>
</html>
```

I need html inside first `<div class="post">` :

```
text <p> text </p> text <a> text </a>
   <span> text </span>
```

with tags.

I can extract only text with xpath: `"(//div[@class="post"])[1]/descendant-or-self::*[not(name()="script")]/text()"`
result = `text text text text text`

I tried: `"(//div[@class="post_body"])[1]/node()"` But I don't know how create string from this.

P.S. Or prompt another way, for example (BeautifulSoup)
Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**`find()`**](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find) method to get the first `div`.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   
soup = BeautifulSoup("""<html>
     <body>
      <div class="post">
       text <p> text </p> text <a> text </a>
       <span> text </span></div>
      <div class="post">
       another text <p> text </p></div>
     </body>
    </html>""")

first_div_text = [child.strip() if isinstance(child, str) else str(child)  for child in soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'post'})]
print(''.join(first_div_text))
```

**Output**

```
text<p> text </p>text<a> text </a><span> text </span>
```

Comment: Thanks, it works with downloaded html by requests only without `.children`
------------>
`first_div_text = [child.strip() if isinstance(child, str) else str(child)  for child in soup.find('div', attrs={'class': 'post'})]`
`print(''.join(first_div_text))`

Comment: Did you know how i can find second or third `<div class="post">`?
Like `(//div[@class="post_body"])[3]` on XPath

Comment: `soup.find('div' attrs={'class': 'post'}).find_next_siblings('div', attrs={'class': 'post'})` gives you an array of first `div` siblings

Comment: Thanks =), and did you know hot to find this xpath by beautifulsoup?
`//td[@class="nav w100 pad_2"]/a[last()]/text()` or `//div[@class="mn1_content"]/div[@class="bx1" or @class="bx1 justify"]`